# Datatable Enable onclick on a specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, html-table

I have a datatable and I want the 2nd column to be the only clickable column.
Here is a picture of the design.

[image: table picture]

I intended the Reference ID column (2ndcolumn) to be the one to be clickable in Javascript form please.
When clicked it will get the data from the column just that.

My table is just the usual `< table > < tr> < td> < /td >< /tr >< / table >`.
I also want it to be dynamic so when I have to insert an array from my database the click for the 2nd column will still work.

Comment: When you say "clickable", do you mean the three buttons on the right?

Comment: no, the column of the Reference ID only.

Comment: Its like when you click the cells on the Referece ID column the data within the cell will be fetched or some alert will pop with the data Reference ID. thanks

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of code that is executed when the cell is clicked.

Comment: It's something like this link https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html but I only want the Reference ID column to be the only clickable cell column

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nx668005/1/

Comment: thank you so much! :D @Acidic

Comment: no problem <3 !

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this

```
$(document).on("click","#dataTbl td:nth-child(2)",function(){
        alert($(this).text());
});
```

Jsfiddle example (click 2nd column) : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/zLykna0p/

Answer (score -1):

You could try this.

```
$('#exampleTable tbody tr').on('click', 'td:eq(1)', function () {
 /* Your function code here */
} );
```